# Why do I get an IntegrityError when calling Django's create_user helper function?

Tags: django

The current Django doc on [Creating users](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#creating-users) says that the following helper function can be used to create a user:

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> user = User.objects.create_user('john', 'lennon@thebeatles.com', 'johnpassword')
```

But when I run this code in the Python shell I get this error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "last_login" violates no-null constraint
DETAIL: Failing row contains (7, <hashed password>, null, f, john, ...
```

Is the documentation incorrect?  I understand that the User object contains a required last_login field but the documentation seems to imply that this helper function will take care of populating it.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind.  I inadvertently didn't run my migrations before attempting this.  That was the problem.